# click() if ($("[id*='string']")) show()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show some elements if the button clicked contains a specific string of text, but my code recognizes only the if. It doesn't show the "else" even if the clicked button doesn't contain the string. I'm trying to solve with the answers and jQuery documentation, but I couldn't achieve the result. Could someone support me to understand what is my mistake?

```js
$('.customize-btn').click(function() {
  if ($("[id*='boat']")) {
      $("#extra-boat").show()
  } else{
      $("#extra-residential").show()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="customize-btn" id="a-boat">BOAT</button>
<button class="customize-btn" id="a-residential">RESIDENTIAL</button>

<div id="extra-boat" style="display: none">EXTRA BOAT</div>
<div id="extra-residential" style="display: none">EXTRA RESIDENTIAL</div>
```

Comment: `if($("[id*='boat']").length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because inside `if ($("[id*='boat']"))` we have a jQuery object and you simply checking if that is a *truthy* value or not, which is always true. Even if you use `if($("[id*='boat']").length)` you will still get the same result, as on both button click that button is present, thus length returns `1` in both cases.

To fix this you need to check if the `id` of the clicked button has text `boat` or not like:

```
this.id.indexOf('boat') > -1
```

Now when you click `BOAT` button, then `this.id` returns `a-boat` and `this.id.indexOf('boat')` returns `2` which is > -1, thus it goes inside `if` statement.

Now when you click `RESIDENTIAL` button, then `this.id` returns `a-residential` and `this.id.indexOf('boat')` returns `-1` which is equal -1 and evaluates to *false*, thus it goes inside `else` statement now.

```js
$('.customize-btn').click(function() {

  console.clear();
  console.log(this.id, this.id.indexOf('boat'));

  if (this.id.indexOf('boat') > -1) {
      $("#extra-boat").show()
  } else{
      $("#extra-residential").show()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="customize-btn" id="a-boat">BOAT</button>
<button class="customize-btn" id="a-residential">RESIDENTIAL</button>

<div id="extra-boat" style="display: none">EXTRA BOAT</div>
<div id="extra-residential" style="display: none">EXTRA RESIDENTIAL</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I got it. The "syntax" of my question was wrong.